# exporting a react component as npm package

Tags: reactjs, npm, ecmascript-6

Says I want to share a simple react component in npm package, to let others use it, must I do this?

```
import SomeComponent from './components/SomeComponent';

module.exports = {
  SomeComponent: SomeComponent
}
```

reference
https://github.com/alanbsmith/npm-example-module/blob/master/lib/index.js

In package.json of the project you can see the main file of the package is build/index.js, but why the author don't just export `components/SomeComponent`, but instead created a wrapper? I understand he use babel, it's to support the code for legacy browser but why use module.exports in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using es6 imports, you should use es6 exports as well for consistency.

```js
import SomeComponent from './components/SomeComponent'
export { SomeComponent }
```

And in your `package.json` set the `main` field to the file after build. such as

```json
{
   "main": "lib/index.js"
}
```

Then people can import it like this:

```js
import { SomeComponent } from 'my-lib'
```

The example you're following looks really outdated, though, and doesn't follow a lot of good practices. [Here's a more modern-looking solution that you'll probably have less trouble with.](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/create-react-library)

Comment: what if you skip the this? put `components/Somecomponent` in `index.js`, and do normal class export. Isn't others can just do `import SomeComponent from 'some-component'`?

Comment: Sure, you can do that too. I was thinking if you, maybe, had multiple components in your library, similar to popular ones like material-ui or semantic-ui. The point being, if you're using ES modules, avoid CommonJS syntax for consistency.

Comment: I did the same and have problem. Any clue why my lib doesn't work? see line 3 of src/index.js https://github.com/thian4/webpack-problem

Comment: Not really sure; it's possible the build is broken somehow. I've edited my answer with a link to an alternative example that might be more helpful